# Paypal Integration with Ionic framework Not Working

Tags: android, html, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

I developed App. In this I integrate cordova-Paypal. I added paypal mobile sdk. but it shows PayPalMobile is not defined occurred  in console.I copied helper.js and sdk.js in js folder. Please help me.

```html
var app=angular.module('starter.payPalService', [])

app.factory('PaypalService', ['$q', '$ionicPlatform', 'shopSettings', '$filter', '$timeout', function ($q, $ionicPlatform, shopSettings, $filter, $timeout) {
    var init_defer;
    /**
    * Service object
    * @type object
    */
    var service = {
    initPaymentUI: initPaymentUI,
    createPayment: createPayment,
    configuration: configuration,
    onPayPalMobileInit: onPayPalMobileInit,
    makePayment: makePayment
    };

    /**
    * @ngdoc method
    * @name initPaymentUI
    * @methodOf app.PaypalService
    * @description
    * Inits the payapl ui with certain envs.
    *
    *
    * @returns {object} Promise paypal ui init done
    */
    function initPaymentUI() {
    init_defer = $q.defer();
    $ionicPlatform.ready().then(function () {
    var clientIDs = {
    "PayPalEnvironmentProduction": shopSettings.payPalProductionId,
    "PayPalEnvironmentSandbox": shopSettings.payPalSandboxId
    };
    PayPalMobile.init(clientIDs, onPayPalMobileInit);
    });
    return init_defer.promise;
    }
    /**
    * @ngdoc method
    * @name createPayment
    * @methodOf app.PaypalService
    * @param {string|number} total total sum. Pattern 12.23
    * @param {string} name name of the item in paypal
    * @description
    * Creates a paypal payment object
    *
    *
    * @returns {object} PayPalPaymentObject
    */
    function createPayment(total, name) {
    // "Sale == > immediate payment
    // "Auth" for payment authorization only, to be captured separately at a later time.
    // "Order" for taking an order, with authorization and capture to be done separately at a later time.
    var payment = new PayPalPayment("" + total, "EUR", "" + name, "Sale");
    return payment;
    }
    /**
    * @ngdoc method
    * @name configuration
    * @methodOf app.PaypalService
    * @description
    * Helper to create a paypal configuration object
    *
    *
    * @returns {object} PayPal configuration
    */
    function configuration() {
    // for more options see `paypal-mobile-js-helper.js`
    var config = new PayPalConfiguration({merchantName: shopSettings.payPalShopName, merchantPrivacyPolicyURL: shopSettings.payPalMerchantPrivacyPolicyURL, merchantUserAgreementURL: shopSettings.payPalMerchantUserAgreementURL});
    return config;
    }
    function onPayPalMobileInit() {
    $ionicPlatform.ready().then(function () {
    // must be called
    // use PayPalEnvironmentNoNetwork mode to get look and feel of the flow
    PayPalMobile.prepareToRender(shopSettings.payPalEnv, configuration(), function () {
    $timeout(function () {
    init_defer.resolve();
    });
    });
    });
    }
    /**
    * @ngdoc method
    * @name makePayment
    * @methodOf app.PaypalService
    * @param {string|number} total total sum. Pattern 12.23
    * @param {string} name name of the item in paypal
    * @description
    * Performs a paypal single payment
    *
    *
    * @returns {object} Promise gets resolved on successful payment, rejected on error
    */
    function makePayment(total, name) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    total = $filter('number')(total, 2);
    $ionicPlatform.ready().then(function () {
    PayPalMobile.renderSinglePaymentUI(createPayment(total, name), function (result) {
    $timeout(function () {
    defer.resolve(result);
    });
    }, function (error) {
    $timeout(function () {
    defer.reject(error);
    });
    });
    });
    return defer.promise;
    }
    return service;
    }]);
```

Controller.js:

```html
controller('MyCtrl' , function($scope,PaypalService){

  $scope.click=function()
  {
console.log("i am call");

 // console.log(error);
PaypalService.initPaymentUI().then(function () {

console.log("i am call 2");

PaypalService.makePayment(1, "Total Amount").then(function (response) {

alert("success"+JSON.stringify(response));

}, function (error) {

alert('Transaction Canceled');

});

});

  };
})
```

Error in console:

```html
ReferenceError: PayPalMobile is not defined
    at payPalService.js:35
    at processQueue (ionic.bundle.js:29132)
    at ionic.bundle.js:29148
    at Scope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:30400)
    at Scope.$digest (ionic.bundle.js:30216)
    at ChildScope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:30508)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (ionic.bundle.js:65428)
    at defaultHandlerWrapper (ionic.bundle.js:16792)
    at HTMLButtonElement.eventHandler (ionic.bundle.js:16780)
    at triggerMouseEvent (ionic.bundle.js:2953)
```

Answer (score 2):

> I copied helper.js and sdk.js in js folder

You should not need to add the helper JS manually. The plugin will create those files **automatically** under /js folder. You simply need to put the following statement **after** cordova.js is imported.

Your index.html should look something like these:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  ...
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="js/paypal-mobile-js-helper.js"></script>
  ...
  </head>
  <body>
  ...
  </body>
</html>
```

Also ensure that you test your app on either Android emulator or iOS simulator ... or better yet, a real Android / iOS device.

Reference: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Cordova-Plugin#your-app-integration